# How to determine cluster membership using FindClusters?

Tags: programming, data-structures, cluster-analysis

I have a 1000 by 3 data matrix in which for each person we have 3 scores. I want to cluster those persons into 8 cluster using Agglomerative method. I did the clusetring by:

```
 class=FindClusters[data, 8, DistanceFunction -> ManhattanDistance, 
 Method -> {"Agglomerate", "Linkage" -> "Complete"}]
```

I want to find out how and which persons are classified into those 8 clusters.In other words, I want to have a vector of class membership for each person (similar to what we can get using     `ClusteringComponents[data,8,1]`).

As an example, suppose we have this data set:

```
data={{3, 2, 4}, {1, 1, 0}, {5, 2, 4}, {2, 3, 2}, {4, 4, 4}, {3, 2, 4}, {3,
   2, 3}, {2, 1, 3}}
```

result of `FindClusters` is:

```
class = FindClusters[data, 3, DistanceFunction -> ManhattanDistance, 
  Method -> {"Agglomerate", "Linkage" -> "Complete"}]

{{{3, 2, 4}, {2, 3, 2}, {3, 2, 4}, {3, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 3}}, {{1, 1, 
   0}}, {{5, 2, 4}, {4, 4, 4}}}
```

through the output it can be seen that persons number 1,4,6,7&8 are classified in first cluster; person number 2 in second cluster and persons number 3&5 are in third cluster. I want to have a vector like:

```
{1,2,3,1,3,1,1,1}
```

then I can determine which person is located in which cluster and how many persons are in each cluster.

I decided to use `FindClusters` because I didn't get reasonable results from `Agglomerate` function for hierarchical clustering. My main aim is doing hierarchical clustering with different linkage functions.

Any help and additional ideas are appreciated.

Amin.

Comment: Could you include maybe a smaller sample of `data`, and the results you expect from a proper clustering?

Comment: @0x4A4D♦ I did.

Answer (score 2):

You can supply an optional label/argument to `FindClusters`. In this case, I've just labeled them with a list of integers

```
class = FindClusters[data -> Range[Length[data]], 3, 
  DistanceFunction -> ManhattanDistance, 
  Method -> {"Agglomerate", "Linkage" -> "Complete"}]

{{1, 4, 6, 7, 8}, {2}, {3, 5}}
```

which is the clustering labels you expected. Or just use

```
 ClusteringComponents[data, 8, 1, DistanceFunction -> ManhattanDistance, 
      Method -> "Agglomerate"]
```

to get the alternative form

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 6, 7}
```

Note that `FindCLusters` and `ClusteringComponents` have pretty much the same options available.

Comment: this is close to what I want but I need to have that final vector which includes cluster membership. I can obtain that vector by using `ClusteringComponents[d, 3, 1]` but not from `FindClusters`.

Comment: What advantage is there to using FindClusters over ClusteringComponents?

Comment: I want to use hierarchical cluster analysis with different linkage functions so I thought that `FindClusters` is more appropriate.Do you have any idea?

Comment: The `Agglomerate` function in `HierarchicalClustering` package didn't work for me (which uses different linkage functions) then I moved to `FindClusters`

Comment: I used your
`ClusteringComponents[data, 8, 1, DistanceFunction -> ManhattanDistance, Method -> "Agglomerate"]`
but it didn't work for me.It gave me some error messages.

Comment: I just copy/pasted it and it worked fine here. Maybe try restarting the kernel.

Comment: It worked for me just after removing `DistanceFunction -> ManhattanDistance`. I'm using Mathematica 8.

Comment: I'm on 9, so maybe it's a version thing. The other thing you might try is to use the `Agglomerate` function itself (in the hierarchical package).

Comment: @amin I don't think v8 should make a difference here. ManhattanDistance has been there since v6 or so.